# Combine objects in array if dates are equal javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, array-reduce

I have an array in Javascript and I need to combine objects if they have equal reminder.date

```
const tasks = [
{
 id: 1,
 title: "call Tom",
 reminders: {
  date: "2022-02-01",
  time: "09:30"
 }
},
{
 id: 2,
 title: "Meet Bred",
 reminders: {
  date: "2022-02-01",
  time: "10:30"
 }
},
{
 id: 3,
 title: "Mail Susan",
 reminders: {
  date: "2022-03-01",
  time: "19:00"
 }
},
```

Output should be like this

```
const combinedTasks = [
{
 id: 1,
 tasks: ["call Tom", "Meet Bred"],
 reminders: {
  date: "2022-02-01",
  time: "09:30"
 }
},
{
 id: 3,
 tasks: ["Mail Susan"]
 reminders: {
  date: "2022-03-01",
  time: "19:00"
 }
}
```

I suppose that I need to use Array.reduce method but I dont have idea hot to do it correctly

Comment: Few questions: 1.) In your expected output, `title` key is changed to `tasks`. Is that intentional?. 2.) The combined object has the reminder time of the first object, how do you decide which time to take?

Comment: 1) yep
2) time is not required

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way you can accomplish this using `reduce()`

```js
let tasks = [{
    id: 1,
    title: "call Tom",
    reminders: {
        date: "2022-02-01",
        time: "09:30"
    }
}, {
    id: 2,
    title: "Meet Bred",
    reminders: {
        date: "2022-02-01",
        time: "10:30"
    }
}, {
    id: 3,
    title: "Mail Susan",
    reminders: {
        date: "2022-03-01",
        time: "19:00"
    }
}];

let combinedTasks = tasks.reduce((combined, x) => {
    // Try to find an existing item in the combined tasks array where the date equals this task item.
    let match = combined.find(y => y.reminders.date == x.reminders.date);
    if (match) {
        // If we find a match, add this task item's title to the combined item's tasks array.
        match.tasks.push(x.title);
    } else {
        // If we didn't find a match, take this task item and turn it into a combined tasks item with a tasks array so that future items in the tasks array can be combined with this one.
        let copy = { ...x };
        copy.tasks = [x.title];
        delete copy.title;
        combined.push(copy);
    }
    return combined;
}, []);


console.log(combinedTasks);
```

Comment: My answer was really close to yours so just kept my comments here, Can you please add a working version as well? Your code looks great and should work well :)

Comment: Thanks!  I've changed my example above to be a snippet.

Answer (score 1):

```
const tasks = [
{
 id: 1,
 title: "call Tom",
 reminders: {
  date: "2022-02-01",
  time: "09:30"
 }
},
{
 id: 2,
 title: "Meet Bred",
 reminders: {
  date: "2022-02-01",
  time: "10:30"
 }
},
{
 id: 3,
 title: "Mail Susan",
 reminders: {
  date: "2022-03-01",
  time: "19:00"
 }
}
]
tasks.sort((a,b)=>{
  return new Date(a.reminders.date) - new Date(b.reminders.date)
})

let output = [];
tasks.map((val,index)=>{
   if(index===0){
      let obj = {}
      temp = [];
      temp.push(val.title);
      obj.id = val.id;
      obj.tasks = [...temp];
      obj.reminders = {...val.reminders};
      output.push(obj);
   }else{
      if(output[output.length-1].reminders.date===val.reminders.date){
         output[output.length-1].tasks.push(val.title);
      }else{
          let obj = {}
          temp = [];
          temp.push(val.title);
          obj.id = val.id;
          obj.tasks = [...temp];
          obj.reminders = val.reminders;
          output.push(obj);
      }
   }
})
```

Try this solution , it works .

```
Output : 
[
  {
    id: 1,
    tasks: [ 'call Tom', 'Meet Bred' ],
    reminders: { date: '2022-02-01', time: '09:30' }
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    tasks: [ 'Mail Susan' ],
    reminders: { date: '2022-03-01', time: '19:00' }
  }
]
```

Output of this code is as expected .
I hope this is helpful .

Comment: `tasks.sort((a,b)=>{
  return new Date(a.reminders.date) - new Date(b.reminders.date)
})`
thank for sharing your solution but I did not understand what is for ?

Comment: This basically sorts with respect to date ... what if your array is of large size and same date objects are not beside each other , so this sort function would be helpful in that case .

Answer (score 1):

you are right, you have to use the `reduce` method.

Use it to loop over your initial array. So for each task, you can watch in your futur array if you have a task at the current task date. Else you can create a new task and add next tasks later.

```
const tasks = [
    {
        id: 1,
        title: "call Tom",
        reminders: {
            date: "2022-02-01",
            time: "09:30"
        }
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        title: "Meet Bred",
        reminders: {
            date: "2022-02-01",
            time: "10:30"
        }
    },
    {
        id: 3,
        title: "Mail Susan",
        reminders: {
            date: "2022-03-01",
            time: "19:00"
        }
    }
];

const combinatedTasks = tasks.reduce((_combinatedTasks, currentTask) => {
    const currentDate = currentTask.reminders.date;
    const combinatedTaskAtCurrentDate = _combinatedTasks.find(task => task.reminders.date === currentDate);
    if (combinatedTaskAtCurrentDate) {
        combinatedTaskAtCurrentDate.tasks.push(currentTask.title);
    } else {
        _combinatedTasks.push({
            id: currentTask.id,
            tasks: [currentTask.title],
            reminders: currentTask.reminders
        });
    }
    return _combinatedTasks;
}, []);

console.log(combinatedTasks);
```

Comment: @RuslanAlmukhanov can you accept this answer please ?

Answer (score 0):

I hope this approach would help you.

```js
const tasks = [
{
 id: 1,
 title: "call Tom",
 reminders: {
  date: "2022-02-01",
  time: "09:30"
 }
},
{
 id: 2,
 title: "Meet Bred",
 reminders: {
  date: "2022-02-01",
  time: "10:30"
 }
},
{
 id: 3,
 title: "Mail Susan",
 reminders: {
  date: "2022-03-01",
  time: "19:00"
 }
}];

let cmbArray =[];
tasks.forEach(x=>{
  if ( item = cmbArray.find(a=>a.reminders.date === x.reminders.date))  
  {
    item.tasks.push(x.title);    
  }
  else
  {
   x.tasks = [x.title];
   delete  x.title;
   cmbArray.push(x);
   }
});

  console.log(cmbArray);
```